# How do I enable/use XSLT document function in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, function, xslt, layout, document

I am trying to write a XSLT file that will process an Android Activity layout xml file and create an HTML equivalent.

In creating/testing out the xslt file, I am using the **eclipse xslt** tools.

One of the roadblocks on this path, is that many values are not held in the Android layout file directly (such as string/text values) but are instead held in a seperate xml file located in the 'values' folder

I have been trying to use the xslt function 'document' to open the strings.xml file but without success.

1. **Q) Are there any eclipse permissions that I need to enable to allow the xslt document function to operate?**
2. **Q) Is there something missing in my understanding of how the document function should operate?**

The line which is contained within the **TextView** template (in the xslt file) that is trying to access the android strings.xml file, is:

**`<xsl:value-of select="document('../values/strings.xml')/String[@name=substring-after(@android:text,'/')]" />`**

- The layout file is in the res/layout folder
- The xslt is in a res/xsl
  folder.
- The strings.xml file is in the res/values folder

Here are the code samples:

**Android XML Layout snippet**:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <!-- This is the full screen vertical layout -->

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"    
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <!-- This is the main content vertical layout -->


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/mainHeadingIndent" >
        <!--  This is the Status Section Vertical content layout -->

            <TextView
                style="@style/HeadingTextStyle"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:text="@string/Status"/>
**The rest of the layout file is intentionally omitted**
```

**Here is the XSLT file**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"
        indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:for-each select="LinearLayout">
                    <xsl:call-template name="LinearLayout">
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="LinearLayout">
        <xsl:variable name="width">
            <xsl:value-of select="@android:layout_width" />
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="height">
            <xsl:value-of select="@android:layout_height" />
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="margin">
            <xsl:value-of select="@android:layout_margin" />
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="orient">
            <xsl:value-of select="@android:orientation" />
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="pos">
            <xsl:number value="position()" format="1" />
        </xsl:variable>

        <div div_pos='{$pos}' Width='{$width}' Height='{$height}' Margin='{$margin}'
            Orient='{$orient}'>
            <xsl:for-each select="LinearLayout">
                <xsl:call-template name="LinearLayout">
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="TextView">
                <xsl:call-template name="TextView">
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="ImageButton">
                <xsl:call-template name="ImageButton">
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="Spinner">
                <xsl:call-template name="Spinner">
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="Button">
                <xsl:call-template name="Button">
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="ImageButton">
        <div id="{@android:id}">
            <xsl:comment>
                ImageButton
            </xsl:comment>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="TextView">
        <xsl:variable name="pos">
            <xsl:number value="position()" format="1" />
        </xsl:variable>
        Text field =
        <xsl:value-of select="@android:text" />
        <xsl:variable name="txt">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains(@android:text,'/')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="document('../values/strings.xml')/String[@name=substring-after(@android:text,'/')]" />
                <!-- 
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@android:text,'/')" />
                -->
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@android:text" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <div id="{@android:id}">
            <xsl:comment>
                TextView Element
            </xsl:comment>
            <p>
                Text pointer is: <xsl:value-of select="$txt" />
            </p>
            <!-- <p>Text pointer is:<xsl:copy-of select="$txt"/></p> <xsl:value-of 
                select="document('../values/strings.xml')/String[@name=$txt]" />
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@android:text,'/')" />
                -->
        </div>
        endoftext
        <br />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="Spinner">
        <div id="{@android:id}">
            <xsl:comment>
                Spinner
            </xsl:comment>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="Button">
        <div id="{@android:id}">
            <xsl:comment>
                Button
            </xsl:comment>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your XML snippet is structurally incorrect.  When showing abbreviated XML you must include the root tag and show both opening and closing tags even if you elide large parts of the actual XML.  If your XML really contains multiple `<LinearLayout...>...</LinearLayout>` tags at top level then it's not valid XML.

Comment: Jim,These are are a combination of nested and consecutive LinearLayouts to give the overal screen layout. I elected not to include the entire layout file as the rest would not have added to the clarity, just taken up room. If you feel happier, I can provide the entire layout file, but the question is really about how to enable the XSLT document function under eclipse.

Comment: Has anyone done any XSLT processing using the eclipse tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've solved it.
The big issue is that when xslt fails, it generally fails silently .... ie no errors

The issue turned out not to be the document function per-se. It was the selection criteria that followed the document function. This had a problem such that there was no selected nodes and hence no output from the statement. This all made it look like the document function was not working.

The big change was that the substring-after clause wasn't/isn't being evaluated against the the right attribute. By splittingg the substring clause up, it started to work.
As they say, it's "FM" (flipping magic)!

Here is what I replaced the document line with:

```
<xsl:variable name='string_value'>
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@android:text,'/')" />
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="$string_value"/>
<xsl:value-of select="document('../values/strings.xml')/*/string[@name=$string_value]"/>
```

This sucessfully pulled the correct value out of the strings.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the document's root element in the XPath (this is very easy to forget):

```
<xsl:value-of select="document('../values/strings.xml')/*/String[@name=substring-   after(@android:text,'/')]" />
```

Comment: Hello, I tried adding the full path, but it didn't help. I agree that the full path probably should be used, however there must still be some other setting etc. I have been playing with the eclipse run configurations, trying to specify other project source files, but have not found the magic combination yet.

If anyone has any experience in setting up run configurations for xslt transformations, I would be interested in picking their brains.